# Nivo slider images flashing when pulled from database

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use Nivo Slider with a database of images. It works, but images don't load properly. Instead, they flash. It appears as though they're completely reloading every time, instead of only on the initial load. It's a strange issue.

It's on this page: http://www.holyfamilyshorewood.org/

Someone else set up the database, so I'm not entirely sure how to fix this issue.

Comment: You url shows landing page with advertisements

Comment: What u mean by flash ? I see it working fine .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue only appears in Chrome. But there is a fix for that.

Instructions are for IIS6 but i guess it is basically the same for IIS7.

1. Open IIS and navigate to the folder in the website which contains the 
   images you're having problems with. Right click it and select Properties:
2. In the dialog window, select the HTTP Headers tab:
3. Tick the Enable Content Expiration box.
4. Set the Expire After option and set it to 30 Minutes, or whatever 
   you're comfortable with.
5. Press OK.

[This is discussed here.](http://support.dev7studios.com/discussions/nivo-slider/561-flashing-before-transitions-in-mac-chrome)